# Custom AVFoundation camera issue

Tags: swift

My preview view looks fine, and everything works right, but when i snap the picture it appears distorted. Both views are the same size, not too sure what is causing the distortion

[image: Preview View]
[image: Captured Image]

Comment: another click by someone else and you'll be able to upload an image showing what you mean. hint hint other readers...

Comment: a wink is as good as a nod to a blind man ;)

Comment: "Both views are the same size, not too sure what is causing the distortion" Well, clearly that sort of _is_ what is causing the distortion. There is much more in the camera's field of view than is shown in the first view, both above and below what you are showing. Therefore, when the picture is taken, and you force the picture into the same size, it distorts vertically.